# Creating a two-dimensional lightning table

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-components

I created a lightning table and wanted to have a two-dimensional table with inline-edit.

My goal is to convert my current to table to something similar to this:
[image]

Currently my table is.

[image]

Anyone who has a reference(blog, video tutorial) on how to create a two-dimensional table?

Also, please see below for my current code.

APEX

```
public class DataTableApexClass {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Recognition_Period_Exchange_Rate__c> getFXrates(){
        return [Select  Period__c, Currency__c, to_Currency__c, Rate__c FROM Recognition_Period_Exchange_Rate__c] ; 
        
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateFXrate(List<Recognition_Period_Exchange_Rate__c> fx ){
        update fx;
    }
    
}
```

Component

```
<aura:component controller="DataTableApexClass"  implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName">
    
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="errors" type="Object" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="draftValues" type="Object" default="[]"/>
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>
    
    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
        <h1 class="slds-text-heading_large">Conversion Rates</h1>
    </div>
    
    <!-- the container element determine the height of the datatable -->
    <div style="height: 800px">
        <lightning:datatable aura:id="dtTable"
                             columns="{! v.columns }"
                             data="{! v.data }"
                             keyField="Id"
                             errors="{! v.errors }"
                             draftValues="{! v.draftValues }"
                             onsave="{! c.handleSaveEdition }"
                             />
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        cmp.set('v.columns', [
            {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Period__c', type: 'name'},
            {label: 'Currency', fieldName: 'Currency__c', type: 'text' ,editable: false},
            {label: 'to Currency', fieldName: 'to_Currency__c', type: 'text' ,editable: false},
            {label: 'Rate', fieldName: 'Rate__c', type: 'number' ,editable: true}
        ]);
        helper.fetchData(cmp,event, helper);
    },
    handleSaveEdition: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var draftValues = event.getParam('draftValues');
        console.log(draftValues);
        var action = cmp.get("c.updateFXrate");
        action.setParams({"fx" : draftValues});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        
    },
})
```

Thank you!